# Phrase said thirty seconds to mars from yesterday

Tags: character-identification

What phrase is said at the beginning of this music video?
There are no subtitles https://youtu.be/RpG7FzXrNSs?t=41s and here
https://youtu.be/RpG7FzXrNSs?t=49s

It sounds like he says mi shong ying but I don't speak chinese.

**The phrase has been identified as 明天的声音 which means "tomorrow's voice" I think.  Not sure what it means by "tomorrow's voice."**

Comment: it might be 明天的声音，search web using this

Comment: @user6065 what is that in english?

Comment: the phrase 明天的声音 is very simple, could use googletranslate, anyhow: tomorrow's voice, (information provided w/o warranty)

Comment: @user6065 Thank that is what google translate said.  Would that mean he wants to create a future for tomorrow or alternative have his people create a voice for tomorrow?

Comment: web search yields a lot of hits, with some English, e.g. https://www.kkbox.com/tw/tc/song/jM9005PIJ0X9WQiT9WQiT0XL-index.html

Comment: "明天的声音" just means "voice of tomorrow". If it means anything else in the video, it's added by the author of the video, not from the Chinese language itself. It's just like you say "voice of tomorrow" in English and give it some symbolic meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He says 明天的声音 (Míngtiān de shēngyīn), which literally means "the voice of tomorrow". I think it's a symbolic answer. The two mandarins ask to the emperor what he desires, whether the fire of the sun (太阳的火, tàiyáng de huǒ) or the ice of the stars (星星的冰, xīngxīng de bīng), and he answers "the voice of tomorrow" (明天的声音). I think it represents innovation: the emperor wants a new, dynamic kind of music.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I plan to accept this as the right answer.  Could this also be interpreted as the voice as tommorow for innovation and or technology?

Comment: @William Of course the phrase has something to do with innovation. The character 的, to be accurate, indicates an attributive relation. So "tomorrow" is a quality (almost like an adjective) refferring to the "voice". If we interpret "tomorrow" as "the future, the innovation", then the meaning is clear: "a new voice, a voice that has the freshness of the future". So, from a grammatical point of view, your translation is a little bit free, but the interpretation is definitely correct.

Comment: @William IMO 'tomorrow' here implies 'new, unprecedented'. 'Innovation' is a little stretchy, and 'technology' is definitely not implied.

Comment: @NS.X. thank you quick question.  Is the concept of an emperor sitting on a thrown like the video outdated?  Today China has a president and he certainly isn't a kid when elected.  Japan has an emperor which is closest to what is shown in the video I believe but obviously the video is in chinese.

Comment: @William It's more than outdated - it is ancient. The video is setting context in ancient China because they are speaking Mandarin. The young emperor is either bored and trying to spite the ministers, or a true music lover aiming a high, seemingly impossible goal, by demanding "the voice from the future" as his birthday performance. But as you knew, the presence of 30stm and this song fulfilled the emperor's order.

Answer (score 0):

It means that 30 Seconds to Mars is the "Voice of Tomorrow."

Comment: Would it be possible to [edit] to expand on this answer?  I, for example, have no idea what "30STM" and "voice of tomorrow" mean.